# Python AES encryption .net decryption Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Tags: .net, python-3.x, encryption, aes

I try to encrypt a bytesArray in Python, and decrypt in .net

I always received the message "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." 
I know it's about padding adjustment, but i did not find how to adjust it.

I send a uuid in bytes to my .net service and need to decrypt it.

My encryption in python

```
def EncryptAES(self,key,IV,byteArray):
        cp = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,IV)            
        return base64.standard_b64encode(cp.encrypt(byteArray))
myBytes = uuid.UUID("8047771c-b1b0-408d-91ad-eacbc03ae6ca")
EncryptAES(Key, IV,myBytes.bytes_le)
```

My decryption in .net is

```
using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
      {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption. 
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
          using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
          {
            csDecrypt.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
            csDecrypt.Close();
          }
          return msDecrypt.ToArray();
        }
      }
```

Always get an execption "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." 
Any suggestion ?

Comment: did you decode the base64? Did you encode IV? Usually, the IV is prepended to the ciphertext then encoded. Also, why do you use RijndaelManaged? Why do you use an archaic mode of operations like CBC?

Comment: Besides possible IV or encoding issues there may also be a padding issue. RijndaelManaged uses PKCS7 padding by default, but Pycrypto/Pycryptodome (which I assume is the Python lib used) does not apply padding automatically. If you intend to use CBC, you have to pad the data before encryption. A Pycryptodome example can be found here [`Crypto.Util.Padding` module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module), but I think Pycrypto doesn't have this module.

Comment: @t.m.adam it's working fine with the tools. Thanks

Comment: @kelalaka you said that CBC is archaic, what is the best library in .net on your point of view ?

Comment: Well, that depends on your need, however, you should use Authenticated Encryption (AE) modes like AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305. AE provides not only confidentialy but also integrity and authentication. As 3.0 [AES-GCM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=netcore-3.0) in .net